# Programmatically add calendar event in Android doesn't sync to web

Tags: android, calendar, synchronization

I'm trying to create an event using the new Calendar API and while it creates an event locally, it never shows up on the Google Calendar. I tried to manually create an event in the same calendar and that synced perfectly. I've seen quite a few similar posts, but none of the answers seem to do the trick.

Here's the code I'm using for Android 4.0+:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, info.getStartTime());
values.put(Events.DTEND, info.getEndTime());
values.put(Events.TITLE, info.getTitle());
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, info.getDescription());
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, this.getCalendarInfo().getId()); //hardcoded to 1, which is my default calendar
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, info.getTimeZone());
values.put(Events.STATUS, Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED);
values.put(Events.HAS_ALARM, 0);

this.getContentResolver().insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

I'm not quite sure what's wrong and I hope someone can help me out! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any solution yet?

Answer (score 6):

My Solution is request sync for calendar provider, it's work for me:

```
    private void requestCalendarSync()
{
    AccountManager aM = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = aM.getAccounts();

    for (Account account : accounts)
    {
        int isSyncable = ContentResolver.getIsSyncable(account,  CalendarContract.AUTHORITY);

        if (isSyncable > 0)
        {
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
            ContentResolver.requestSync(accounts[0], CalendarContract.AUTHORITY, extras);
        }
    }
}
```

permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: How we know when sync is completed?

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`its easy, the line

```
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, this.getCalendarInfo().getId()); //hardcoded to 1, which is my default calendar
```

actually tells android to add event to LOCAL android calendar .... i assume that you would like to add it to calendar synced to your gmail account .... so instead of

```
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, this.getCalendarInfo().getId());
```

try

```
 values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 2);
```