# Programmatically add calendar event and synchronize with google calendar

Tags: android, events, calendar, synchronization

I'm writing an app which add events to mobile phone calendar using ContentResolver insert methode. User can choose calender to synchronize. So I choose one of the google account calendar and try to add event. Everything seems to be alright, events shows up on mobile calendar but doesen't synchronize. I thought this event will be synchronized and will appear also on other devices with same google account and on google calendar website.

I found similar questions but ansewrs did't help:

[Programmatically add calendar event in Android doesn't sync to web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672478/programmatically-add-calendar-event-in-android-doesnt-sync-to-web)

[sync event added programmatically with google calendar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918968/sync-event-added-programmatically-with-google-calendar-in-android)

Using android API level 15.
Maybe I should use Sync Adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Only for checking: Have you tested in another device or emulator?

I had the same problem, and my conclusion was that internal calendar became corrupted (because I updated it connecting as SYNC_ADAPTER).

My only solutions was to remove the account, and reinstall it, and then, my Calendar start sync again.